# Combining Substrings in php

Tags: php, arrays, substr

I would like to add all strings which start with a whitespace to another string.

```
<?php
$array = array(
   "1" => "android",
   "2" => "apple",
   "3" => " iphone 6",
   "4" => " iphone 5",
   "5" => " iphone",
   "6" => "blackberry",);

$phone = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, 1)==' ') {  
        $apple = (end($phone));
        $string = [$apple = $apple.$value];
    } else {
        $phone[] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```

If I try to put the strings together I get three strings instead of one.

```
var_dump ($apple=$apple.$value);

'apple iphone 6 iphone 6'
'apple iphone 5 iphone 5'
'apple iphone iphone'
```

But I would like to have a string like that.

```
'apple iphone 6 iphone 5 iphone'
```

Comment: Do you have to use that data structure?

Comment: Why does your string start with `apple` as it doesn't start with a space?

Comment: @NigelRen is right, If you meant `I would like to add all strings which start with a whitespace to another string.` then the output should be `iphone 6 iphone 5 iphone` where you got **apple** by the way?

Comment: @NigelRen I mean at the end I would like to have all string which starts with a whitespace at the end of the that ( "2" => "apple",) string. But maybe it is better to get first a string like iphone 6 iphone 5 iphone. Hopefully, you understand a bit what I mean because my English isn't so good.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you should probably change the data array to something like this.

```
<?php
$array = [
    "android",
    "apple" => [
        "iphone 6",
        "iphone 5",
        "iphone",
    ],
    "blackberry",
];

$phones = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $phones[] = $key . ' ' . join(' ', $value);
    } else {
        $phones[] = $value;
    }
}

foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    echo $phone."\n";
}
```

Example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/470506a86804886345d233c373ac834e43ef818d

It makes more sense to use a nested array for this sort of thing. I can't see that you're using the keys so I wouldn't add them in as you have, and would stick to an ordinary array.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand it, it's a case of adding (in this example) any entry starting with a space the the entry just before that in the array.

This looks thorough the array and each time it finds a space it adds the entry to the end of a built up string.  Then when there isn't a space, it will check if there has been any additions and add it to the output values (`$list`) and reset the output to the text.

```
$array = array(
    "1" => "android",
    "2" => "apple",
    "3" => " iphone 6",
    "4" => " iphone 5",
    "5" => " iphone",
    "6" => "blackberry",
    "7" => " Curve"
);

$list = [];
$out = "";
$added = false;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, 1) == ' ') {
        $out .= $value;
        $added = true;
    }
    else    {
        if( $added )   {
            $list[] = $out;
        }
        $out = $value;
        $added = false;
    }
}
if( $added )   {
    $list[] = $out;
}
print_r( $list );
```

This outputs (note I added a Curve - the phone sitting on my desk ATM :-/ )...

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple iphone 6 iphone 5 iphone
    [1] => blackberry Curve
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code just a little (actualy I removed 2 rows and added 1). You can achieve desired results with this:

```
$array = array(
   "1" => "android",
   "2" => "apple",
   "3" => " iphone 6",
   "4" => " iphone 5",
   "5" => " iphone",
   "6" => "blackberry",);

$phone = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, 1)==' ') {  
        $phone[count($phone)-1] .= $value;
    } else {
        $phone[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($phone);
```

I used this

```
$phone[count($phone)-1] .= $value;
```

instead of this

```
$apple = (end($phone));
$string = [$apple = $apple.$value];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of `join()` like I did below.

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "1" => "android",
    "2" => "apple",
    "3" => " iphone 5",
    "4" => " iphone 6",
    "5" => " iphone",
    "6" => "blackberry",
);
$stringList = array();

foreach($array as $value) {
    if(substr($value,0,1)==" ") {
        array_push($stringList,$value);
    }else{
        // do something else
    }
}

$string = join("",$stringList);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: I apologise for uploading an image of code snippet but I did because I couldn't format the code and add well formated using code block.

Comment: If you post the code someone will probably edit the post for you. That is a much better solution than posting images of code. There really isn't anything worse.

Comment: Okay I edited your post and added a few spaces at the beginning of the iphone items so it actually displays something - but this is not a very good answer. I was just annoyed by the image :)

Comment: Formatting the code should not be too hard for anyone. Copy-paste the code, highlight it, click on the `{}` button in the toolbar. Much easier than taking a screenshot and uploading it to the post.